# ODBC to JDBC datatypes mapping

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, types

Where can I find description of how to map ODBC datatypes to JDBC?
Or maybe anybody knows where source code of a jdbc-odbc bridge driver can be downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge is bundled with the Java 2 SDK Standard Edition...

Check out the FAQ's at Sun - http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/faq.html

Comment: Yeah, but what about sources?

Comment: You can download the source for all the the SDK, hence the ODBC to JDBC bridge at - http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver),

> Sun provides a JDBC-ODBC Bridge
>   driver. sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.
>   This driver is native code and not
>   Java, and is closed source.

But I've downloaded sources (jdk-6u3-fcs-src-b05-jrl-24_sep_2007.jar), and the driver's source is really there: j2se\src\share\classes\sun\jdbc\odbc\JdbcOdbcDriver.java

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this page for JDBC to database column type mappings:  [Mapping SQL and Java Types](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#table1) .

However, I did notice that the table does not show that a JDBC CLOB will work with a Memo column of Access.